# Android:add PayPal payments

Tags: android, paypal

I'm building an Android application, integrated with Paypal.
I wrote this:

```
PayPal pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_faq);

    CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
    launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

            payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("8.25"));

            payment.setCurrencyType("USD");

            payment.setRecipient("bss_45@gmail.com");

            payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

            Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, getApplicationContext());

            startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
        }});
    lay.addView(launchSimplePayment);
```

When i run the emulator, the app crashes. Log cat says:

```
05-03 12:48:41.768: E/AndroidRuntime(748): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-85
05-03 12:48:41.768: E/AndroidRuntime(748): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 12:48:41.768: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.paypal.android.b.e.j(Unknown Source)
05-03 12:48:41.768: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.paypal.android.b.e.v(Unknown Source)
05-03 12:48:41.768: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.paypal.android.b.e.c(Unknown Source)
05-03 12:48:41.768: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.paypal.android.b.f.run(Unknown Source)
```

The library that i've imported is PayPal_MPL.jar.

Have i need to import other jar? or what?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Comment: oK, here says that i hav to load the "other necessary MPL components", and it brings me to the download page ... probably is a dumb question, but i have to download java-rest-api ... right?

Comment: no need to download java rest api for run simple paypal app please check this example https://github.com/vivdub/SimplePayPalIntegration  and try this one with latest PayPal_MPL jar file

Comment: ok i'm gonna test it ... but are you sure that it works? I ask you it because lots of people recommend me tutorials saying that they work fine, but they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPL library that you're using is being deprecated. It's recommended that you use the new [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) instead if possible.

Comment: I'm not working in the US and so the new SDK is not available for me

Comment: OK, back here after a long time. I used SDK when it was made available in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Pay pal sandbox accounts, the issue will be solved.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you would post a code example explaining how to do it.